How to store a function parameter to an excel file
I am trying to store a function parameter 'n' to an excel file however I receive an error:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'to_excel'
I have a function that takes:
def test(alpha,a,x,y,n):
I need to store n (which is a single integer) in an excel file where I tried:
n.to_excel('n.xlsx')
However I receive the error as mentioned before. I tried to make an empty DataFrame and write n into the array which allows me to run the code however there is no value in the file. I have printed n in the function and it returns the integer so a bit confused on why I cannot save this value to an excel  file?

You need a python library that can save to excel, excel files are far more than a simple text file

I have saved data before in excel files using pandas. Even if I write this in a text file, there seems to be nothing.

Hello John, you are right, saving pandas dataframes is much easier. The problem in your code is that your variable n is an integer, the integer class doesn't have a method to save in Excel, so you can't call non existing method n.to_excel.

Basically when pandas do 'df.to_excel' it takes your data and hiddenly uses functions from openpyxl modules to save your data. As I said in previous comment integer/float values doesn't have this method.

You will need to install library openpyxl which can create and modify excel. The final code will look something like this:
from openpyxl import Workbook

def test(alpha,a,x,y,n):
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active

    ws.append([n])

    wb.save("sample.xlsx")

test(alpha=3, a = 4, x = 10, y = 15, n = 100)

